# value and ng-model are conflicted

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I am working on an angular form with the possiblity for the user to send updates of their data and to cancel the edit if needed.

I found out that I should save the edit in a seperate variable. So here is some code:

```
//if editor is turned off it shows the saved value
<div data-ng-hide="editorEnabled" class="margin-bottom-top">{{document.title}}</div>

//if the editor is turned on it should save the edits in another variable to keep the older one
<input data-ng-show="editorEnabled" class="margin-bottom-top" data-ng-model="document.edit.title" value="{{document.title}}" type="text">
```

So now I can access both - the former title and the new edited title. But I want  the former title to show up as value in the input-field, so the user can see what the current value is and doesn't have to type it in again. With a placeholder it is working, but it's not what I want. When I inspect the element I can see, that the right value is bind but it doesn't show up.

I know that ng-model and value conflict each other and therefore it's not working. I also tried ng-value and it's not working either. Is there any solution for this case?

Comment: could u please provide a plunker, jsfiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
$scope.document.edit.title = $scope.document.title
```

and remove `value=""` from the input

Comment: Thank you. I now use 'data-ng-init="document.edit.title=document.title"'.

Comment: That would work however its better practise to set it in the controller of that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use both, set value to the to the ng-model

```
$scope.document.edit.title
```

And it will automatically set value to that input.